# Particle System does not stick to the mesh if the mesh is moving (global,local coordinate-system?)

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, coordinates

I want to create something like a fire elemental, so I have to work a lot with the smoke simulation. In the flow objects I use FlowType: Fire. Now I've created a nice burning head, which is pretty easy, because the fire raises just straight to the top. And now I want burning arms too, but I have no idea how to give the fire the matching direction. I'm using a particle system to control the direction, but as soon as I rotate the mesh or something the particle system does not rotate with the mesh. I think the particle system is in the glocal coordinate system, but I would need it in the local coordinate system, so that it sticks with my mesh.

I hope I could clarify my question for you, thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an issue you get when the modifiers are in the wrong order.

[image]

The modifiers are applied from the top down. In this example the particles are generated then the armature deforms the mesh which leaves the particles behind.

Check that the modifier for the particles or smoke is last in the list. Use the little up/down arrows to the right re-arrange the order.

You may want to alter the gravity settings for the particles to alter their direction. Particles usually fall down by default, you also only need a lifetime of one frame for them to generate smoke. [Force fields](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Force_Fields) can also be used to control the flow of particles and smoke.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit troubled understanding your questions. For testing I just put a particle emitter on a cube and made that cube rotate. The particle system was animated with it and even the cube's rotation was added to the particle direction.

My guess would be that the cause of your problems lies more in the smoke / fire simulation. Have you tried animating the domain object with it (although that's probably tough regarding that you wanna animate a complete character)?

(Sorry but Stack Exchange gives me a 404 when trying to edit my last answer) I tried this a bit further, so my previous answer is partly incorrect. You don't have to animate the domain. - You have a mesh with a flow (fire) inside the domain - You have a particle system on that mesh and Flow Source set to that particle system - You animate the mesh, that way animate the particles and also the fire I admit that a particle system doesn't offer too much control over the exact particle vectors. Still those can be controlled by various settings like emitter object, emitter geometry, force fields etc. You cannot really set global / local vectors for some obvious reasons, the particles should be random, they should emit from faces (thus having an orientation from the face normal, otherwise the would just go up or to the side through the mesh)